# RTF data in Crystal Report 13 with Data field

Tags: visual-studio-2013, rtf, crystal-reports-2013

I have problem to display RTF data in crystal report.My RTF data showing with formatting but data fields value not showing.

My RTF Data Below:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Arial;}}
{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\qc\cf1\ul\b\fs28 BLOOD GROUP\ulnone  \fs24 
\par \pard 
\par 
\par 
\par \pard\tx2160\tx4320\tx6480\b0\tab ABO GROUP\tab  \b :\b0  \tab\b\{bgrp\} 
\par \pard\tx2160\b0 
\par \pard\tx2160\tx4320\tx6480\tab Rh GROUP\tab  \b :\b0\tab\b\{rh\}
\par 
\par 
\par 
\par }
```

I need too show value but it showing {bgrp} and {rh} instead show the data like O Positive.I use vs2013 .
Please Help me.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1KZf.png)

Comment: Your question is very difficult to read as it is unformatted. Please read the [help] pages to see how to write a good question and how to format your question neatly.

Comment: I just edited .. Please check and solve my problem.